# Measurable Subset of $(0,1)$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number. If $x\in(0,1)$, we can write $x =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{a_n}{p^n}$ with $a_i\in\{0,1,2,....,p-1\}$.
For each $k\in\mathbb{N}$,
define

$$E_k = \{ x \in (0,1) : x = \sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{a_n}{p^n} , a_{k+1} \geq 1\}$$

I want to show that $E_k$ is measurable for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
I am stuck with this problem for quite some time now. Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Tip: Make curly parentheses in MathJax by escaping them like so `\{1,2,3\}` (that produces $\{1,2,3\}$)

Comment: $E_k=\left[\frac{a_{k+1}}{p^{k+1}},\frac{a_{k+1}+1}{p^{k+1}}\right) ?$

Comment: How are you getting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{k+1}}{p^n}$$ can be written as $$p^{-{k}}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{b_j}{p^j} $$

(by just writing $b_j = a_{k+j}$).